# Problems with R.java in gen folder after creating two packages

Tags: android, r.java-file

I have created two packages in eclipse.
The actitivites in both the packages use the some common xml files and few diffrent ones.

But once i build the project the R.java for the second package is not created.
there is no second package in the gen folder.

I manually build the project and also kept build automatically but nothing is helping me to generate the r.java file for the second package.

Thanks 
Sudhanshu Bhatt

Comment: R.java can be only one, everything gets created in one R.java only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one R.java for the entire project. So what you are seeing is correct. You can have n number of packages under src directory and still there will be just one R.java under gen. Mind you, R.java should not be tampered with as it is self-generated.

Comment: Ok, but in the second package when i set the content view i have to import that r.java file of the previous package and when i run the activity in the second package it crashes, saying that the resources cannot be found.

how do i use the resources of the r.java file in the activities of the second package ?

Comment: Can you post the logcat trace. You can also try a clean build.

Comment: Yes, try clean and build and check the R.class import sometimes eclipse automatically import the android.R not your won R class.

Comment: i tried it occrued once but vanished again . will try doing it again in a new project. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Only one R class is generated, and it is under the package set under `<manifest>` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

For all package is generated only one R file. it is not important haw many package you create always be one R file